# regex to validate input for inches value

Tags: angularjs, regex

I am trying to use a regex to validate the format of a text input for inches value:

```
<input name="widthfield" type="text" ng-pattern="/^([0-9]{1,2}((\'\')?|(\'\'[0-9]\/[0-9]{1,2})*))|([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$/" placeholder="ie 18''1/2 or 18.25" ng-model="data.boardWidth"  ng-required="true"/>
```

It doesn't work, can you help me check my regex ?

If I divide it in two parts :

```
/^([0-9]{1,2}((\'\')?|(\'\'[0-9]\/[0-9]{1,2})*))$/
```

and

```
/^([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$/
```

then they both work well separately.

I need the format to be inches or decimal inches
18.25 or 18''3/4

Thanks

Comment: Side comment:  Inches are represented by a double-quote, not two single quotes.

Comment: You can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. And then it would also be shorter to use `\d\d?` than `\d{1,2}`

Comment: Also, [`^\d+((\.\d+)|(\'\'|\")(\d+\/\d+)?)?$` works](https://regex101.com/r/eV3uS2/1) (If you use @Wiktor's solution combined with this)

Comment: `18"3/4` is not a common way to represent fractional inches. The correct representation, at least in the U.S. and Britain, is `18¾″`, which we approximate with `18 3/4"`. Note the punctuation comes after the fraction, just as it's read: "Eighteen and three fourths inches," not "eighteen inches and three fourths."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `|` implicitly encapsules both alternatives. So these two are the same:

```
(regex1)|(regex2)
regex1|regex2
```

In your case this means that alternative 1 starts with `^` but doesn't end with `$` and the other way around for alternative 2. It works fine for me if I change it like this:

```
/^([0-9]{1,2}((\'\')?|(\'\'[0-9]\/[0-9]{1,2})*))$|^([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ng-pattern="(\\d{1,2}(|\\x27\\x27|(\\x27\\x27\\d/\\d{1,2})*)|\\d{1,2}(\\.\\d{1,2})?)"
```

The apostrophe should be represented with `\x27`. **If you have a double quote, replace the `\x27\x27` with `\x22`.**

When you pass the pattern as a string, angular will automatically add the `^` and `$` anchors, thus, no need adding them.

Here is a [sample regex demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kxptZ08JsnEYfYoCTjwH?p=preview).

Comment: thanks but I get this error with your code: angular.js:12722 Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 1-1 [\] in expression [(\\d{1,2}(|\\x27\\x27|(\\x27\\x27\\d/\\d{1,2})*)|\\d{1,2}(\\.\\d{1,2})?)].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%201-1%20%5B%5C%5D&p2=(%5C%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D(%7C%5C%5Cx27%5C%5Cx27%7C(%5C%5Cx27%5C%5Cx27%5C%5Cd%2F%5C%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)*)%7C%5C%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D(%5C%5C.%5C%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)%3F)

Comment: That means you did not copy/paste my solution exactly as it is. You must have added `/.../` around it.